# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sensor_msgs_py'

Tags: python, ros2

I am trying to run a ROS2 example taking inspiration from [here](http://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Releases/Release-Galactic-Geochelone.html?highlight=pointcloud#python-point-cloud2-utilities-available).

```
import sensor_msgs_py.point_cloud2
```

I can build my package without any problem with `colcon build --symlink-install` but when I then run my ROS node I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sensor_msgs_py'`
```

I tried by installing:

```
pip install common_interfaces
```

But it did not work. I am sure that there is an easy solution but I could not find it so far.

Of course, I don't have any error if I use:

```
from sensor_msgs.msg import PointCloud2`
```

instead of

```
import sensor_msgs_py.point_cloud2`
```

But since I want to use python, I would like to understand how to use `sensor_msgs_py`.

EDIT: I also tried the following without success:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-foxy-common-interfaces
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: From the documentation - http://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Releases/Release-Galactic-Geochelone.html?highlight=pointcloud#, the desired feature did not come into ros2 until the Galactic release.  It looks like you are trying to pull in from foxy, which is an older release.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `sudo apt-get install ros-foxy-sensor-msgs-py`

Comment: See my comment under OP thread: this feature didn't come into ros2 until Galactic.  Nevertheless, I gave +1 since `sudo apt-get install ros-galactic-sensor-msgs-py` worked for me

Answer (score 0):

The install failed because the package is a debian that should be installed via `apt` and not a Python package. Instead, run `sudo apt install ros-$ROS_DISTRO-common-interfaces`

Comment: I forgot to say it but I tried that too with: 
`sudo apt-get install ros-foxy-common-interfaces` . 

I edited my question.